# Updates units in new iTunes Connect reports

Tags: report, itunes, updates

The 'Sales and Trends' section in iTunes Connect was heavily redesigned.
The info popup for **Units** says

> "By default, updates and previous purchase downloads are excluded."

But how can I switch from 'sales' to 'updates' as from now ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. Choose Filter and select "Transaction Type" and then select "Updates"

[image: Transaction Type for iTunes Connect Reports]

This is what is look like when you are done:

[image: Update filter for iTunes Connect report]

You can also download the report and then do some number crunching on the data export. Pivot off of "Product Type Identifier" and look for either 7 or 7F:

[image: Product Type Identifier Table]

Comment: One have to distinguish between  

1. main data filters "Filters" and  
2. additional chart filters "Overview | By Territory | By Platform | By Category | By Content Type | By Transaction Type".

Comment: Is this still accurate? Updates aren't showing for me.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest incarnation of iTunesConnect (as of 2016), you need to click on the "Sales & Trends" section and then add a filter for "Transaction Type".

One of the choices will be "Updates".

And your results may look like the below screenshot (well, hopefully with even more updated installs :-)

[image: I only have less than 1000 updates]